# How to get all the pids of a single application (multiple processes) from the package name programmatically?

Tags: android, pid, uid, multiprocess

It's possible that an Android application has two or more processes.

I want to know how can I get all the processes' identifier (**pid**s) from the application's **package name** or **uid** programmatically? (I'm not very familiar with the relationships of **uid & pid & package name**).

Thanks for anyone that can help.

Comment: No one knows? Or is it that I asked the question in the wrong way?

Comment: Yes, one android application has more than one processes.